# SQL Server - Get a count of continious occurance data

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can a get count of concurrence occurance of data in sql server. Let me ellborate through an example.

I have a data as below:

[image]

Let's say, i have **ID** with value 2. Here, we can see that **NAME** column have a value 'Shyam' of that **ID** and the value 'Shyam' occurs continuiously 3 times. Now i want to get a count of that 'Shyam' that occurs continiously. How can I write this query on SQL Server??

Comment: too lazy to type it - but you will use a LAG function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are starting with `id = 2` and you want the number of names that are continuous, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,             
             row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as seqnum_name
      from t
      where id >= 2
     ) t
where seqnum = seqnum_name;
```

You can add `min(name)` if you also want the name.

This works because the sequence numbers are the same only for the initial rows where the names are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the lag function with a case expression to determine concurrent occurrences and finally summing that result

```sql
SELECT
    NAME,
    SUM(similar_occurrence) as no_occurrences
FROM (
SELECT
     ID,
     NAME,
     CASE
         WHEN LAG(NAME) OVER (ORDER BY ID ) = NAME THEN 1
         ELSE 0
     END similar_occurrence
FROM
    testdata
) t
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING SUM(similar_occurrence) > 0
```

Output

| NAME | no_occurrences |
| --- | --- |
| Shyam | 3 |

````
```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) as no_unique_name_occurrences
FROM (
SELECT
     ID,
     NAME,
     CASE
         WHEN LAG(NAME) OVER (ORDER BY ID ) = NAME THEN 1
         ELSE 0
     END similar_occurrence
FROM
    testdata
) t
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING SUM(similar_occurrence) > 0
````

Outputs

| no_unique_name_occurrences |
| --- |
| 1 |

[View Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f11a1e345545a40b21f80f79644e5e21)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This gives a result of entire row. I only need a count of continious data

Comment: @ElonMusk  I've updated the answer with a having clause and the associated demo fiddle. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

The contiguous count of cases:

```
WITH cte AS (
       SELECT *
            , CASE WHEN LAG(name) OVER (ORDER BY id) = name THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS edge
         FROM test
     )
   , groups AS (
       SELECT *
            , SUM(edge) OVER (ORDER BY id, edge) AS agroup
         FROM cte
     )
SELECT *
     , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY agroup) AS n
  FROM groups
;
```

[Test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=242a5c5f653ae5b91584b00551f035a4)

Result:

[image]